# getting error while changing the embedded server from tomcat to jetty

Tags: spring-boot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-02T14:44:37.628+05:30 ERROR 14020 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:602) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.sai.QuizApp.QuizAppApplication.main(QuizAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.newSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:339) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.getSessionHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:432) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:257) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:180) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:301) ~[jetty-webapp-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:228) ~[jetty-webapp-11.0.15.jar:11.0.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.<init>(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:28) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(JettyServletWebServerFactory.java:159) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
```

```
              <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to downgrade the Servlet API to 5.0 as Jetty 11 does not support Servlet 6.0. Assuming that you're using `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you can do so by setting a property in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
</properties>
```

That said, unless you really have to use Jetty, I would recommend sticking with the default Tomcat web server as it supports Servlet 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

try debug mode, To enable debug mode, you can add the following line to your `application.properties` file `debug=true`